# Differences between ADOMD.net and Analysis Services OLE DB Provider (especially regarding authentication)

Tags: oledb, ssas, adomd.net

I'm attempting to connect to a SQL Server Analysis Services cube on a remote server which is not connected to the domain I'm connected to.

I can connect to the cube with Excel after providing username and password. Now I'm trying to connect to the same cube via code.

**Unsuccessful connection via AdomdConnection**

Using ADOMD.net (AdomdConnection) for SQL Server 2008 R2 I try to connect with this connection string:

```
Data Source=SRV1;Initial Catalog=Name of Cube;User Id=RemoteAccount;Password=***
```

This connection fails on the Open method of the connection. *Interestingly the "user id" and "password" properties are allowed, because if the syntax was wrong you get a KeyNotFoundException.*

**Successful connection via OleDbConnection**

I can successfully connect if I use OleDbConnection instead and the following connection string (copied from the Excel connection):

```
Provider=MSOLAP.4;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SRV1;Password=***;Initial Catalog=Name of Cube;Data Source=SRV1;
```

So my questions are:

- Can someone explain this behaviour? I thought AdomdConnection just used OleDB underneath?
- Is there a way to connect to a SSAS
  instance with AdomdConnection using
  username and password?
- Are there any
  further differences between
  AdomdConnection and OleDbConnection?

All downloads are available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ceb4346f-657f-4d28-83f5-aae0c5c83d52).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for the sake of others coming here for help, I'd like to pitch in. There is a good article by Marco Russo [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/execute-dax-queries-through-ole-db-and-adomd-net/) talking about why ADOMD.NET is better than OLE DB. I was hoping to try using OLEDB but after reading this article, I feel that the best solution is indeed ADOMD.NET with the MSDPUMP.DLL for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the AdomdConnection succesfully with the username / password keys, but the difference is that I'm connecting to a HTTP data source. The solution I'm using is that I tunnel OLAP traffic over HTTP via IIS 7 as described [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx). The user name and password are then impersonated by IIS to Windows credentials.

Note: Disable Anonymous and Windows Authentication in IIS. I only got it working with Basic Authentication. For enhanced security, use SSL.

Comment: I am doing the exact same, using the infamous MSDPUMP.DLL. But speaking with some Microsoft representatives during the last Data Summit, they have advised me to try alternatives since this DLL is hardly maintained and they consider this method 'outdated'. Sure, I get it. It works (it works for me as well). But besides what they told me, the deployment of an IIS, HTTPS certs, etc seems like an annoying overhead (and hop/bottleneck), particularly if there is a decent alternative. I am now looking into OLEDB to see how it compares. I'm worried since it might not support all queries. :(

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot connect the cube with excel, then you cannot connect it with the code.

The difference between ADOMD.Net and OleDb connection is that, the OleDb MSOLAP provider can be used to send MDX, DAX and DMX queries to an Analysis Services database. The result can only be a scalar or a table, so you cannot use an MDX query returning results on more than two axes. When you use a DAX query, the result will always fit well in a table, you can use a DataReader class to get the result.

We prefer mainly ADOMD.NET on OleDb due to the presence[Connection bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/251601/run-mdx-query-with-parameters-using-oledb) which hasn't been resolved.

In order to connect to SSAS instance with ADOMD.NET we need to add the following line in web.config file ( After creation of console application in Visual studio 2012)

Since we will be using Windows authentication to connect to Microsoft Analysis Services 2005, this addition of line in the web.config file is required to impersonate a user having access to the Analysis Services.

We need to configure the IIS server by creating a new application pool.

Following  MSDN link will give other parameters of the ADOMD.NET connection String.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectionstring